# Как получить данные с полей html(php mysql) в js

Tags: javascript

Можно ли как то корректно получить данные с таблицы строки которой выводятся циклом php из mysql?

что бы при нажатии на кнопку в столбце выводились значения (из этой строки)

**index.php**

```
<? 
echo "<table>";
$sqlusers = 'SELECT * FROM users';
foreach ($conn->query($sqlusers) as $rowusers) {
    echo "<tr>
              <td><span id='name' name='name'>".$rowusers['name']."</span></td>
              <td><span id='id' name='id'>".$rowusers['id']."</span></td>
              <td><span id='email' name='email'>".$rowusers['email']."</span></td>
              <td><input type='button' value='getValues' onclick='getvalues()'></td>
         </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValues(){ 
    alert(id);
    alert(name);
    alert(email);
}
</script>
```

вывод например в алерты, мне только логика получения не понятна

**пробовал так**, результат тот что надо но думаю это костыли, и так не правильно

```
<? echo "<table>";
$sqlusers = 'SELECT * FROM users';
foreach ($conn->query($sqlusers) as $rowusers) {
                        echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td><span id='name' name='sfname".$rowusers['id']."'>".$rowusers['name']."</span></td>
                                <td><span id='id' name='sfid".$rowusers['id']."'>".$rowusers['id']."</span></td>
                                <td><span id='email' name='sfemail".$rowusers['id']."'>".$rowusers['email']."</span></td>
                                <td><input type='button' value='getValues' onclick='getValues(".$rowusers['id'].")'></td>
                            </tr>
                        ";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValues(vak) {
    var name = document.getElementsByName('sfname'+vak)[0].value;
    var id = document.getElementsByName('sfid'+vak)[0].value;
    var email = document.getElementsByName('sfemail'+vak)[0].value;
    alert(id);
    alert(name);
    alert(email);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Честно говоря, не понял, что должно происходить... Данные и так уже вывелись. Или вы хотите, чтобы по клику на строке в alert'е появлялись данные из этой строки?

Comment: выводится таблица с значениями из базы, в каждой строке в конце кнопка

Comment: `id` должен быть уникален на странице. В Вашем же случае получается, что будет столько `id='name'`, сколько записей в таблице users. Сделайте так, чтобы `id` для каждой ячейки таблицы были уникальны. Например, `id="name' . $rowusers["id"] . '"`. И только после этого Вы сможете обращаться к этим ячейкам и выводить из данные

Comment: нажимаем на кнопку, и выводятся данные через js с этой строки

Comment: Сделайте так, чтобы id для каждой ячейки таблицы были уникальны. Например, id="name' . $rowusers["id"] . '" (см 2 кусок кода)

Comment: мне сама логика получения не понятна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вытащить текущую нажатую кнопку через `event.target`;

Посмотрите пример.

Но у него есть минус - сильная зависимость от структуры `html`.

```js
function getValue(event) {
  const button = event.target;
  const [val1, val2] = [...button.parentElement.parentElement.children].map(m => m.innerText);
  console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td><button onclick='getValue(event)'>get</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td><button onclick='getValue(event)'>get</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td><button onclick='getValue(event)'>get</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Лучше использовать уникальный `id`.

```js
function getValue(id) {
  const row = document.querySelector(`.myTable tr[id="${id}"]`);
  const [val1, val2] = [...row.children].map(m => m.innerText);
  console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

```html
<table class='myTable'>
  <tr id='1'>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td><button onclick='getValue(1)'>get</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='2'>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td><button onclick='getValue(2)'>get</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='3'>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td><button onclick='getValue(3)'>get</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: да, спасибо, это подходит

Answer (score 0):

ID - уникальный аттрибут для элемента и лучше отталкиваться либо от его уникального значения, либо использовать другие способы для получения нужных данных.

Можно попробовать так:

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td class="id">10</td>
  <td class="name">John Smith</td>
  <td class="email">john@smith.com</td>
  <td><input type="button" value="show data" onclick="showData(this);" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="id">20</td>
  <td class="name">Adams Bar</td>
  <td class="email">adams@bar.com</td>
  <td><input type="button" value="show data" onclick="showData(this);" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function showData(el){
  var parentTR = findAncestor(el, 'tr');
  alert(
   findTextOfChildElByClassName(parentTR, 'id') + " " +
   findTextOfChildElByClassName(parentTR, 'name') + " " +
        findTextOfChildElByClassName(parentTR, 'email')
  );
}

function findAncestor (el, sel) {
    while ((el = el.parentElement) && !((el.matches || el.matchesSelector).call(el,sel.toLowerCase())));
    return el;
}

function findTextOfChildElByClassName(el, className){
  var childEl = null;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (el.childNodes[i].className == className.toLowerCase()) {
        childEl = el.childNodes[i];
        break;
      }        
  }
  
  return childEl.innerText;
}
//-->
</script>
```

В данном случае привязку делал к аттрибуту *class*.